# How can i programatically switch my wifi to wifi Printer for printing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, printing, wifi

In my project there is a print option where we print a simple pdf file.

At this point my printing code is working perfectly but every time i need to open and change my"iPhone settings ->Wifi->my wifi network"  to a printer network "iPhone settings ->Wifi->select printer network" .

How can i programatically connect from my wifi network to wifi printer on a click of UIButton ?

Please help.

Comment: No, you can't change Wi-Fi connection using your iOS App.

Comment: but android able to do the same, then why not iOS?

Comment: Complain to Apple for not including this in the API.

Comment: @naveenkumarp You have to be clear that Android OS is not equal to iOS. They don't have the same features.

Comment: @naveenkumarp Apple restricts this for user privacy (if you can scan for Wi-Fi networks, you can determine the users's location) and power conservation, many Wi-Fi operations are power intensive.